# regarding continuity of function on $\mathbb R$

Tags: analysis

Given a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ .Define two sets $A$ and $B$ as follows:
$$A = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 : y<f(x)\} , B = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 : y>f(x) \}$$
Prove that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ if and only if both $A$ and $B$ are open in $\mathbb R^2$.

Here I have proven the left to right side part but was not able to prove from right to left side part.I have tried contrapositive but failed. So if any hint is provided then it will be of great help.

Comment: Sorry I am new to these,I will repost my question properly next time.

Comment: What's the difference between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Sorry for my fault, I have edited it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a<b$ and $U=f^{-1}(a,b)$. If $x \in U$ the $(x,a) \in A$. Hence there exists $r>0$ such that $|x-x'| <r$ implies $f(x') >a$. Similarly you can show that there exists $s>0$ such that $|x-x'| <s$ implies $f(x') <b$. Let $\delta =\min \{r,s\}$. Then $|x-x'| <\delta$ implies $a<f(x')<b$ which means $x' \in U$. We have proved that $U$ is open. Since any open set is a union of open intervals it follows that inverse image of any open sets is open. Hence $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you Sir  for your help .I have understood your way,but can I use here the contrapositive method to prove?

Answer (score 0):

We have $A=B $ ??

Define $g(x,y):= f(x,y)-y. $ then $g$ is continuous and $A= g^{-1}((0, \infty)).$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Sir ,please forgive for my mistake ,I have edited it properly